# Convert stage dummy variables into a df that shows skipped stages using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my current df where it has a 1 if the id goes through a given stage and this is constructed by having a 1 if it is currently in a given stage or if it has gone through that stage in the past.

| id | stage 1 | stage 2 | stage 3 | stage 4 | stage 5 | stage 6 | close lost | close won |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

This next table is what I am looking to generate. I want to only know if a given id has skipped a stage or not and I want it to be sequential like it is in the previous table.

| id | stage 1 skip | stage 2 skip | stage 3 skip | stage 4 skip | stage 5 skip | stage 6 skip | is_closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: can you clarify the output? Why is the first row if id `2` for `stage 3 skip` 0 but 1 for the rows below?

Comment: @mozway the reason if it a 0 for the first row of id 2 is because in the first table that row only made it to stage 2. Because it hasnt made it to any later stages yet, it can skip stage 3. I hope that makes sense. id 2 doesnt skip stage 3 until the next row where it goes straight to stage 4

Comment: @Patelra95 The value for `stage 6 skip` at row `4` should be `0`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sharma It should be a 1 for stage 6 skip because if you look at the 4th row you can see that it goes from stage 5 straight to close lost. This means that stage 6 was skipped.

Comment: @Patelra95 That means we have to consider `close` columns as well?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma The close column does need to be considered because that it technically considered the last stage.

Comment: @Patelra95 Assuming you are referring the column `Close Lost` by `is_closed`, then in that case `is_closed` should be `0` at row `4` because it is not skipped?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma is_closed refers to if either close lost or close won have occurred in the original table. If its easier to see you can assume in the second table that is_closed is the close stage and keep it as a 0 instead of 1 as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

- Set the index to `id` then change the `dtype` of remaining columns to boolean
- Invert the columns and calculate the cumulative maximum along the columns axis, this would serve as the indicator which shows the last available stage that an `id` has gone thorugh
- Negate the logical mask from step 1 so that it will show us stages that are skipped by given `id`, then take the logical and with the mask from step 2. The resulting mask will give us the indicator of which stages are skipped by the given `id`

```
m = df.set_index('id').astype(bool)
s = (m.loc[:, ::-1].cummax(1).loc[:, ::-1] & ~m)

s = s.drop(['close lost', 'close won'], axis=1).astype(int).add_suffix(' skip')
s['is_closed'] = (m['close lost'] | m['close won']).astype(int)
```

---

```
print(s)

    stage 1 skip  stage 2 skip  stage 3 skip  stage 4 skip  stage 5 skip  stage 6 skip  is_closed
id                                                                                               
1              0             0             0             0             0             0          0
1              0             1             1             0             0             0          0
1              0             1             1             0             0             0          0
1              0             1             1             0             0             1          1
2              1             0             0             0             0             0          0
2              1             0             1             0             0             0          0
2              1             0             1             0             1             0          0
2              1             0             1             0             1             0          1
```

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSharma, this worked like a charm!

Comment: @Patelra95 Happy coding!